# Can I access the click event in a polygon wrapped in a clipPath

Tags: angular, svg, polygon, clip-path

When I wrap my polygons in a clipPath tag, I cannot access their click event.

```
<image clip-path="url(#black-5)" width="100%" height="100%"
                    xlink:href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/450055/pexels-photo-450055.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260"
                    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice">
                </image>
<clipPath id="black-6">
                    <polygon id="L12" (click)="testClick()" class="cls-1"
                        points="710.21 46.69, 738.75 96.12, 674.51 108.55, 653.14 46.69, 710.21 46.69" fill="#FFF">
                    </polygon>
</clipPath>
```

Comment: This is not a properly set up clip path, it has to be used somewhere.

Comment: I added the image that I am using for the clipPath. The idea is that I want to put an image over several polygons using the clip-path. however when I do it, I can no longer click on the polygon.

Answer (score 1):

To start of with, you haven't set up your SVG properly, the clip path has to be used on another element. Secondly, please set up an example with code on Stackblitz, Codepen or any other service for us to use.

To capture mouse events, add the click handler to the top svg and parse the event's target to find out what element has been clicked.

In the Stackblick example I've set up for you, check the console's output.

- When the target is SVGUseElement, you're clicking on the element
  using the clip path.
- When the target is SVGPathElement, you're clicking within the clip
  path but outside the element being clicked.
- When the target is SVGSVGElement, you're clicking outside the
  clipping path

https://angular-buumnd.stackblitz.io

Comment: Stack snippets are much better than anything outside of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @RobertLongson Can you get stack snippets to work with Angular?

Comment: You don't need angular here as the answer is basically no. Your other examples could just be raw SVG without any toolkit.

Comment: Sure, I agree, but Stackblitz is very efficient and fast, so I think it serves the purpose even though this example could have been done without it. I'm personally more used to Stackblitz, so that's what I used in order to answer quickly. Just any kind of example with working code would have been good to have.

Comment: https://codepen.io/ivo-nikolov/pen/rNBvXPE This the whole code. i need to access the polygons in order to get the x and y of the central point, in order to move the image in the bottom on the board and I cannot do so because of theclip path which I unfortunately need for the image to be cut with the size of the board

Comment: @QuestionOne , here you have a fork of your pen:
https://codepen.io/fredrikborgstrom/pen/gOYKaGV
 You need to open dev tools (F12) to see the console's output of mouse events. The 'target' property is probably what you need, but maybe the 'path' can be of interest to you as well.
And of course you have the clientX and clientY which tells you coordinates of the mouse when clicked. Good luck!